# What are the low hanging fruits of a SQL Server 2014 migration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, upgrade

I have read about new features and changes of the SQL Server 2014 version. But I still don't know the benefits every server will have by upgrading (from 2008 R2) to 2014?

Are there any new features / functionality (low-hanging fruits) every instance and database will benefit of immediately, without a single change to the database schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2014 you get the new [cardinality estimator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2014/04/01/sql-server-2014-s-new-cardinality-estimator-part-1.aspx) which could see your queries get better plans and therefore execute more efficiently.

A good reason to upgrade from 2008R2 is that it is on extended support meaning it is unlikely to receive anymore updates and only SQL Server 2012 SP2 + versions are able to operate with TLS 1.2 [see here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052404)